# Are props passed from parent components available only in render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling to understand where I can use props passed by parent's component. It seems that the props are available only in render() method.

The piece of code below is **working perfectly** but I can't **easily serialize** the form data and do "e.preventDefault()" thing (can I?)...*it'd be better written in const Form = props => { ... })*

```
class Form extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
        >
          <TextInput />

          <button className="Button">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

BUT this **does not work** (props are not available in onSubmit method):

```
class Form extends Component {
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = ... serialized form data;

    this.props.handleSubmit(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        >
          <TextInput />

          <button className="Button">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Am I misunderstanding some react.js approach? Is there possibly some .bind(this) missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding . Also you can use esnext class property syntax https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there possibly some .bind(this) missing?

Yes you need/can use `.bind`, or use [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), because now `this` does not refer to `Form`

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  ...
}
```

or just use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
<form
  onSubmit={ (e) => this.onSubmit(e) }
>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've totally forgotten about the possibility of using the arrow function in this case.